# PostgreSQL: replace string with datetime

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, type-conversion

I have a varying character field (datestring) with a timestamp and I want to convert it to timestamp type. I can successfully create a new timestamp column (see below) and populate this column with a formatted version of the column datestring but I would rather not create a new field, I just want to replace the datestring field with a timestamp version of itself.

So this works fine:

```
ALTER TABLE service_areas ADD COLUMN newdate timestamp
update service_areas set newdate = to_timestamp(datestring, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
```

But I'd like to do something like:

```
update service_areas set datestring = to_timestamp(datestring, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
```

Suggestions?

Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a USING clause

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE foo(a varchar);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES('2013-07-15');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN a TYPE date USING to_date(a,'YYYY-MM-DD');
ALTER TABLE
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! (I am new to the site and tried to mark this as the correct answer, let me know if I did not do it correctly).